# PrintStream does not create a new file

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

The following code gives a file not found exception (underlying the **openFileOutpu**t bit) even before compiling. I've changed the manifest to allow for external storage write and read permissions. Any help would be appreciated!

```
    public void AddWordMethod(View view) {

            EditText NameEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NewWordID);
            String NewName = NameEdit.getText().toString();
            EditText SurnameEdit =  
               (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NewSurnameID);
            String NewSurname = NameEdit.getText().toString();

    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(openFileOutput("added_names.txt", MODE_PRIVATE));
    output.println(NewName + "\t" + NewSurname);
    output.close();}}
```

Comment: Do you get an exception or a compiler error? Do you got the lines red with an error indicator, or the app is crashing when you launch it?

Comment: Hi - It gets underlined with an error indicator. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no '`PrintStream` does not create a new file' problem here, and it is not possible for code to throw an exception 'even before compiling'. What is actually happening is a compilation error *during compiling,* which you have misquoted.

Answer (score 0):

In Java every Exception must be wrapped with try catch. The red line that you see in your code is a compiler error tells you, that you didn't put the try catch in place.

Try doing it as fallow:

```
public void AddWordMethod(View view) {

    EditText NameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NewWordID);
    String NewName = NameEdit.getText().toString();
    EditText SurnameEdit =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NewSurnameID);
    String NewSurname = NameEdit.getText().toString();

    PrintStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new PrintStream(openFileOutput("added_names.txt", MODE_PRIVATE));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    output.println(NewName + "\t" + NewSurname);
    output.close();
}
```